# plug in a dongle to use bluetooth, No Bluetooth Found

Tags: 22.04

[image]
This might looks like duplicate question but I've tried all available solutions on various platforms.
I don't see any leading error while executing below command

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
```

Here is the output of above command

[image]

Please help me if anyone of you have faced the same, I've not option other than installing windows which I hate :(

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Here is the output of requested command

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't try "all available solutions" because every solution is hardware specific. But you didn't try to determine the hardware. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` command. AS TEXT PLEASE, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Also please provide information about the Ubuntu release.

Comment: Provided requested response

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Terminal output is plain text. And please post the FULL output of the given command.

Comment: Run in the terminal as root: sudo journalctl -f Then connect the USB dongle. Find the vendor code and device ID for the Bluetooth adapter(USB dongle): $ lsusb | grep bluetooth -i